# Alphablend function

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi, alphablending

Is it possible to make certain part of image transparent using alphablend function?

Can I create an image which contains certain area with RGB(0,0,255) and when I draw that image only that area should be tranparent.Is it possible with AlphaBlend function. Is yes, then How?

I was reading about alphablend , but it still not clear to me. I guess we need to specify alphachannel while creating the image. If alphachannel is not there for a particular pixel then that pixel cannot be made transparent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I guess we need to specify alphachannel while creating the image. If alphachannel is not there for a particular pixel then that pixel cannot be made transparent?

Yes, the [`AlphaBlend` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183351.aspx) is intended to draw images that already have alpha channel information saved along with them. These will be 32 bit-per-pixel (bpp) images, meaning that they contain red, green, blue, and alpha channel information. You can think of the `AlphaBlend` function as similar to `BitBlt`, except that it preserves any transparent or semi-transparent pixels the image may contain.

The key to this function is its last parameter, which is a [`BLENDFUNCTION` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183393.aspx). The documentation has this to say:

> **`ftn` [in]**  The alpha-blending function for source and destination bitmaps, a global alpha value to be applied to the entire source bitmap, and format information for the source bitmap. The source and destination blend functions are currently limited to `AC_SRC_OVER`.

So what that means is that your image is assumed to already contain a pre-multiplied alpha channel. The `AlphaBlend` function respects those values when drawing your image, but you can adjust its opacity by specifying a value between 0 and 255 for the `SourceConstantAlpha` member of the `BLENDFUNCTION` structure. If you set this value to 255, only the per-pixel alpha values of the bitmap are used. If you set it to 0, it is assumed that your image is transparent. Setting it to something in between will cause your image to be drawn with some degree of translucency.

> Is it possible to make certain part of image transparent using alphablend function?

Can I create an image which contains certain area with RGB(0,0,255) and when I draw that image only that area should be transparent.

It sounds to me like what you're trying to do (as [kolenda suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11645713/366904)) is something called color keying. Basically, you use a particular color (like RGB(0,0,255)) everywhere in your image that you want to be transparent, and then you tell Windows to draw your image with RGB(0,0,255) as the transparent key color, meaning that every pixel that is RGB(0,0,255) in the original image will be transparent in the image that gets drawn.

Yes, this is possible, and it's actually rather common in Windows for things like toolbar button icons, etc. Generally, they'll use the color fuchsia (RGB(255,0,255)) because that's such an ugly color that no one would use it ordinarily in an image.

The function responsible for this is the [`TransparentBlt` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145141.aspx) (again, similar to `BitBlt`, even named with the same pattern). The important thing with this one is it allows you to specify a color key—that is, a particular color that you want it to treat as transparent when it draws the image. That's the last parameter, `crTransparent`. In your case, you'd want to specify `RGB(0,0,255)`.

If you want to get *really* fancy, you can combine the effects of `TransparentBlt` and `AlphaBlend`. Basically, you'd call `TransparentBlt` first to draw your image into a temporary device context (DC) with all of the key color treated as transparent, and then use the `AlphaBlend` function to blend the contents of that temporary DC to the target DC with whatever transparency effects you desire.

But even though this is possible, and kind of cool once you write the code to get it to work, [RED SOFT ADAIR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11645988/366904) still has a point when he says that GDI is not designed for transparency. You can't go much further than the simple transparency effects described here, and it certainly isn't easy to do.

If you need to do very much drawing with transparency, you probably want to switch to the [GDI+ APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533798.aspx) instead. These have much better support for transparency, and they're actually designed as C++ APIs (although they have C fallbacks), so they are structured into classes, which makes them even easier to work with.

The only caveat to GDI+ is that it is only natively supported on Windows XP and newer. If you have clients still running Windows 2000 or older versions, you will need to redistribute the GDI+ DLL (`Gdiplus.dll`) in order for them to run your program.  That's becoming less and less of a barrier to entry nowadays, but it's still something worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

Alpha-blending as a technique is used when you have separate `alpha` channel as your transparency data.

What are you looking for is probably `color keying` which means that you use some particular color as a `transparent` one.

Answer (score 1):

Alphablending afaict is not possible with WinGdi functions itself. This can be done with newer APIs like GDI+ etc.

An overwiev about the different Windows grahic APIs can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If you want just transparent drawing (where a specified color will result in transparency), you can use [TransparentBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: How, then, do you explain the presence of the [`AlphaBlend` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183351.aspx)?